# Setting Up FTP Server with AT&T Wireless

Tags: networking

I just switched to AT&T from Verizon. I had Verizon's Home Fusion (or whatever they call it now. I live in an area with no wired service, so 4G is my only option). I now have AT&T's "Unlimited Plus One Line" plan.

Issue: I have an FTP server setup to transfer files for work. This worked fine with Verizon but does not work with AT&T. I can't figure out my IP address. My router reports one ip address (same one reported by the 4G modem), Google tells me another (type "what is my ip" in search), and whatismyipaddress.com gives a third one! How can I have 3 ip addresses?

I have tried all 3 addresses and none connect to my FTP server. I have port forwarding setup properly and firewall shouldn't be an issue as this worked fine on this PC with Verizon.

Can I setup an FTP server with the service I have? What the heck is my ip address?

Equipment:

- [NETGEAR 4G LTE Modem – Instant Broadband Connection (LB1120)](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/mobile-broadband/lte-modems/LB1120.aspx)
- [Linksys WRT160N](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t80000003K7b9AAC) running DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std

While typing this, a "Similar Question" popped up: [Setting up a public FTP server on an Access Point](https://superuser.com/questions/1241217/setting-up-a-public-ftp-server-on-an-access-point) and one of the comments says that addresses starting with 10.x.x.x are "private". My router has one of these. And since my router address is different than public I am probably behind a "carrier grade NAT". Does that mean I'm out of luck? Are there other options?

```
4G/Router:              10.193.194.xxx
Google:                 166.171.58.xxx
whatismyipaddress.com:  107.77.204.xxx
```

Comment: They are probably using carrier grade NAT.  Can you edit into the post the first 3 octets of each IP you mentioned.

Comment: @Tyson Ok. I've updated.

Comment: Yep, carrier grade NAT 10.x.x.x is a private network address.  You will need to ask AT&T if you can get a public IP, if they can do it it’s probably an extra monthly charge.  The reason they do this, is they don’t have enough IPv4 addresses to go around, this is how to stretch the limit.